# Modifing Open Real Estate Booking Form

Tags: php, yii

I am using free version of the script Open Real Estate.
I need to add some extra fields to the booking page.
I added the HTML part in "/themes/classic/views/modules/booking/views/_form.php" and I now need to add them to the PHP code, part which I find a bit tricky.
Can anyone suggest how to approach the problem?
PS: The extra fields should only be sent by email to the owner and not listed in the admin panel.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not tricky at all, you just have to take it one step at the time.
Since you already modified the _form file I think the next step is to add properties to the model. In your model add public properties that should be named exactly like the name of the input type in the view. You can set the validation for them if you like but if you don't care just list them as safe ( which means safe to assign without any custom validation ). Now go into the appropriate action of the controller and after you mass assign the $_POST to the model and use those properties in your mailer function after booking has been saved. Alternative approach is to do the mailing in afterSave() in your model.